# Function-Maximum and Minimum

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Given that f is a real valued non-constant differentiable function such that $f(x)f'(x)\le0$ , for all real $x$, then it follows that:

(A) $f^2(x)$ is increasing function

(B)  $f^2(x)$ is decreasing function

(C)  $f(x)$ has no critical point

(D)  $f(x)$ does not have any real root

My approach is as follow

Case 1:
$f(x)>0$ and $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing function

Case 2:
$f(x)<0$ and $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing function

In both cases $f(x)$ has imaginary roots and no critical points, hence C and D are correct answer

Lets take the case $F(x)=f^2(x)$
Then $F'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)\le0$

Hence $F(x)$ is monotonically decreasing function. Hence (B) is also correct.

I managed to solve this problem using hypothetical cases , is there any other approach to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you could construct some classes of functions that fulfill your conditions, and those classes have no real root/critical point, does not mean that there do no exist other functions that do have those properties.

For example

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{, if } x \le 0 \\
0   & \text{, if } x > 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

fulfills the conditions of your problem (if "non-constant" means it takes at least 2 different values), but has many real roots, so (D) is wrong (it does not follow from the problem conditions).

(C) is similiarly wrong, as

$$f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x & \text{, if } x \le 0 \\
0   & \text{, if } x > 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

also has lots of roots.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(f^2)'=2ff'\leqslant0$, $f^2$ is decreasing.

Comment: I am revisiting this question we need to prove that the above equation has no real roots , how do we do that

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such. Besides, was my answer helpful?

Comment: YES IT WAS HELPFUL

Comment: Then perhaps that you could mark my answer as the accepted one.